# Vuex state is not updating before load vue component?

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

Sometimes token commits to Vuex store and sometimes not.

```
userLogin() {
  axios.post('api/login', this.logindata,)            
  .then(response => {
    let token = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('token'));

    this.$store.commit('setToken', token);
    this.logindata = {};
    this.loaded = true;
    this.success = true;
    this.$router.push({path: '/'});
  });
}
```

Here is the `store.js`:

```
export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    token: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('token')),
    isLoggedIn: !!localStorage.getItem('token'),
    cart: []
  },
  mutations: {
    setToken(state, token) {
      state.token = token;
    },
  }
});
```

Here is Vue Frontend:

```
mounted: function () {       
  if (!this.$store.state.isLoggedIn) {
    this.$router.push('/login')
  }
}
```

Result: sometimes it redirects to login and sometimes not. Any help about it?

Answer (score 0):

I would make a `v-if` on the component you want to load only after login where you would have a `computed` property bound to it, that way you have a listener.

```
<myComponent v-if="computedProperty"/>
computed: {
 computedProperty(){
   return this.$store.state.isLoggedIn
...
```